# Is there a alternative of @AfterMethod in junit?

Tags: java, junit, testng

I am unable to use `@AfterMethod` in junit as it belongs to testng.Is there any alternative for `@AfterMethod` in junit.

Comment: Did you try googling for "junit aftermethod"? Documentation of the JUnit equivalent is the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit 4 uses [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) and [`@After`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) to indicate methods that need to be run before or after unit tests, which is effectively a method.

So the direct equivalent to `@AfterMethod` is just `@After`.

[`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [`@AfterClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) are before/after the whole class.