# my after method does not work everything seems normal to me but it is skipping. Any suggestion?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

my aftermethod refuse to run I dont what i am doing wrong.
i tried couple codes but i am still getiing java.lang.NullPointerException any suggestion ?

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/eshanmostafa/eclipse-workspace/TestNG/chrome_ios/chromedriver ");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
    


    
    

@Test
public void test() {

String title = driver.getTitle();
System.out.println(title);

}
    


@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowswer() {
    
    try{ Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
       }catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println("Nothing to do with it");
          } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, what you want to achieve, because your example looks a little incomplete.
I completed it, with my guesses, to a working, simple selenium test:

```html
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyTest {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void doBefore() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromedriver/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);

    }

    @After
    public void closeBrowswer() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Nothing to do with it");
        }
    }
}
```

Some notes on this:

1. @AfterMethod
   That's not part of JUnit, but an annotation of TestNG. As [Is there a alternative of @AfterMethod in junit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258269/is-there-a-alternative-of-aftermethod-in-junit) shows, @After is the corresponding method in JUnit
2. NullPointerException
   I guess, you get a NullPointerException in your code, because you assign the variable driver in a block - and not as a member variable of the class. It's hard to say, because the start of the block is missing, but there is a closing curly brace, so I assume, it's originally in a block.
   A variable in a code block is limited to that block. The variable drive in the "After"-method is then an other variable - the member variable of your class and probably this variable wasn't assigned with a value. So you get an NPE.